# java ee - persistance dynamic query

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence

I am quite new with java ee and persistance technology.
I am trying to write a dynamic query. The details: 
There is a data table ('**newsactivites**'), it's look like this:

```
id   type
4    UploadVideo
4    CreateBlog
1    UploadPicture
10   UploadVideo
10   CreateBlog
```

And furthermore there is an enum:

```
public enum Type {
      UploadVideo("show.uploadedVideo"),
      UploadPicture("show.uploadedPicture"),
      CreateBlog("show.createdBlog");
}
```

So I would like to write a method like this:

```
private List<Type> activities=new ArrayList<Type>();

@CollectionElements()
@Column(name="type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JoinTable(name = "newsactivities", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") })
public List<Type> getActivities() {
      return activities;
}
```

But i want give back just one id's activities at given time:

```
public List<Type> getActivities(int id) { }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I read your model right (I am not sure), you should have an entity class `Newsactivities` (in a class `Newsactivities.class`) with a foreign key `type`. Then you would need a `List<Newsactivities>` (and not a `List<Types>`):

```
public List<Type> getActivities(int id) {
    TypedQuery<Newsactivities> tq = em.createQuery(
      "SELECT n FROM Newsactivities n WHERE n.type=:type, Newsactivities.class);
    tq.setParameter("type", id);
    return(tq.getResultList());
}
```

Comment: No, I have not an entity class Newsactivites. In data table the ids means users and the type column means an 'activity' of the user. If there are activities a given user, i want give back all type of activities.

Comment: But you have a datatable Newsactivities?

Comment: Yes, the datatable's name newsactivites.

Answer (score 0):

You have an associated to the `Type` of the object,like you write:

```
public class A{

private List<Type> activities=new ArrayList<Type>();

@CollectionElements()
@Column(name="type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JoinTable(name = "newsactivities", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") })
public List<Type> getActivities() {
    return activities;
}
}
```

then, you need a `Repository`, like this:

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A,Long>{
@Query("select a.activities from A a where a.id=?1")
List<Type> findTypeById(Long id);
}
```

now, you can use `findTypeById`, This requires that you have `A` object